# how can i copy and pass components from a parent to a child component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I copy 2 components from the parent and pass to a child component?

```
<!-- this is only shown on desktop -->
<div>
    <my-custom-component [myInput]="myInput1"></my-custom-component>
    <my-custom-component [myInput]="myInput2"></my-custom-component>
</div>

<!-- this is only shown on mobile -->
<my-other-component> 
    <!-- how can i pass all my-custom-component in to this component? -->

    <!-- this works but I'd like to use an elementRef or something similar -->
    <my-custom-component [myInput]="myInput1"></my-custom-component>
    <my-custom-component [myInput]="myInput2"></my-custom-component>
</my-other-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by wrapping the html I needed in a template. I could then inject it anywhere on the page I needed it:

in the html:

```
<ng-template #exampleTemplate>
    <my-custom-component [myInput]="myInput1"></my-custom-component>
    <my-custom-component [myInput]="myInput2"></my-custom-component>
<ng-template>

<my-other-component>
    <ng-container #exampleContainer></ng-container>
</my-other-component>
```

in the component:

```
@ViewChild('exampleContainer', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })
    exampleContainer: ViewContainerRef;
@ViewChild('exampleTemplate', { static: true })
exampleTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.exampleContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.exampleTemplate);
}
```

Then in the html of my-other-component:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```